# Restkit cannot serialize request to xml

Tags: ios, xml, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit 0.20.0 to work with API (xml).

But when I try to make XML POST request and setup mapping, request body is always `null`

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url:4465/paci/v1.0"]];

[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeXML;
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeXML];
```

Mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *createServerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[createServerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"name": @"name",
                                                           @"description": @"description",
                                                           @"ramSize": @"ram-size",
                                                         }];

RKRequestDescriptor *createServerDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:createServerMapping objectClass:[NSMutableDictionary class] rootKeyPath:@"ve" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:createServerDescriptor];
```

Object:

```
IBCreateServer *createServerRequest = [[IBCreateServer alloc] init];
createServerRequest.name = @"web40";
createServerRequest.description = @"testtest";
createServerRequest.ramSize = @"512";
```

post Object:

```
[objectManager postObject:createServerRequest path:@"ve" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
```

And the result of this request is:

```
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/xml";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
}
request.body=(null)
```

Body is always null. What i am doing wrong? This happens only with request, response XML parsing works correctly.

**EDIT:** if I serialize to json, it works correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request descriptor is wrong. It should be:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *createServerDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:createServerMapping objectClass:[IBCreateServer class] rootKeyPath:@"ve" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

This tells RestKit what your source class is and what mapping it should use when you ask it to post an instance of that class. The mapping tells RestKit what to convert the instance into (a mutable dictionary) so that it is ready to serialise to XML.

Comment: This seems to work better, but request body is still null http://pastebin.com/q9TSavU7

Comment: Json serialization works correctly. This problem occurs only if I use XML request

Comment: Try turning on trace logging for mapping and see what it says.

Comment: Here is a result: http://pastebin.com/MjsyKPmV
Looks like restkit 0.20.0 cannot serialize XML

Comment: Argh, forgot about that (I never use XML), you're right. You could implement it yourself if you need to. You'd need to implement the RKSerialization protocol (if you can find an XML serialisation library it should be easy).  [http://restkit.org/api/latest/Protocols/RKSerialization.html]

Comment: Thanks. I am using this class, but looks like it supports only xmlToOjbect (response), but not objectToXml (request) https://github.com/RestKit/RKXMLReaderSerialization/blob/master/RKXMLReaderSerialization.m